# Dynamics AX x++ can't close first form

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-365-operations

I see a strange case when open form twice using FormRun

```
    static void Job780(Args _args)
    {
        FormRun formRun;
        Args args = new Args();
        ;

        args.name(formstr(Form1));

        formRun = ClassFactory.formRunClass(args);

        formRun.init();
        formRun.run();
        formRun.wait();
    }
```

If I run this code twice then I see 2 forms but I can't close first form before I close the second.

I tried it on several instances, and different versions (2009, 2012). Cleared cache and *.auc fiels. Same result.

The question is how to fix it. I mean how to make form to be closed properly in any order. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because you are using `formRun.wait();`.

Use either `formRun.wait();` if you want to stop execution until the form is closed.

Or use `formRun.detach();` if you want to let the form run separately.